# How do I set the default schema when configuring AS400JDBCXADataSource in Spring or as Tomcat Resource?

Tags: tomcat, ibm-midrange

Moving from the following Tomcate Resource Definition:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/test"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="user"
          password="pwd"
          driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"
          url="JDBC:AS400://1.2.3.4:50000/TEST;prompt=false" />
```

to JTA (Atomikos), I'm wondering how to set the default schema:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/test"
          auth="Container"
          type="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
          factory="com.atomikos.tomcat.BeanFactory"
          uniqueResourceName="jdbc/test"
          xaDataSourceClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource"
          xaProperties.user="user"
          xaProperties.password="pwd"
          xaProperties.serverName="1.2.3.4"
          xaProperties.prompt="false" />
```

What's the correct property?
I think it's the same question for Spring.

Comment: Try the databaseName property.

Comment: Thank you, JamesA, I tried that without success.

Answer (score 0):

In AS400 database schema is determined by "libraries" connection property, in the url. By default, it uses schema named like current username.
So in your case, it should probably be something like:
`xaProperties.libraries="myschema"`