# Atomikos in Tomcat 8, how to configurate JDBC resource with XA in the server.xml to as400?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to configure a JDBC XA resource in Tomcat 8 that can be used with Atomikos to implement transactions using Spring and JTA.

However, I have not found a tutorial describing how the configuration must be done. The documents I have read begin with the configuration in Spring and Atomikos, but they do not mention how to configure Atomikos with Tomcat. In addition, their examples configure JTA/XA transactions with PostgreSQL and/or MySQL, but not mention databases in AS/400.

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612102/how-do-i-set-the-default-schema-when-configuring-as400jdbcxadatasource-in-spring/45921971#45921971), but the response is not clear to me.

Does someone know how to configure a JDBC/XA resource in the `server.xml` configuration file used by Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use databases in IBM AS/400-iSeries machines using the (1) Universal DB2 driver, if that option has been enabled in the server, or (2) the traditional [IBM Toolbox for Java](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/) or [jt400/JTOpen opensource library](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/).

Some years ago, I used the [JTOpen JDBC XA drivers](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCXAConnection.html) for accessing the databases and the datafiles in the iSeries. It works just like any other JDBC driver.

- If you want to create an stand-alone program, IBM provides documentation for [implementing JDBC XA distributed transactions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/jdbcxa.htm) using JTOpen drivers.
- If you want to use an application server, you only need to configure the datasource (just like any other database). You may check IBM documentation for [configuring XA datasources in Websphere](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0407_woolf/0407_woolf.html).
- If you want to use Atomikos, the XA-datasource must be configured just like you [configure any other JTA/XA connection](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringTransactionsEssentials#XA_Drivers). There is [a forum entry](http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default.asp?community.6.2158.4) describing an example.

> I have found this post, but the response is not clear to me.

Check the documentation for [Atomikos-Tomcat integration](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35). The resources must be defined in the `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml` file. There is an [example](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat7Integration35#Example_application) you can download to understand the Atomikos-Tomcat configuration.